# Scapy: callback, no output with pkt.show()

Tags: python, scapy

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import TCP, IP, sniff

def ip_callback(pkt):
    pkt.show()
    print 'IP', pkt.src, pkt.sport, '--->', pkt.dst, pkt.dport

def icmp_callback(pkt):
    print pkt.show()

def tcp_callback(pkt):
    pkt.show()
    print 'TCP', pkt.src, pkt.sport, '--->', pkt.dst, pkt.dport

def udp_callback(pkt):
    pkt.show()
    print 'UDP', pkt.src, pkt.sport, '--->', pkt.dst, pkt.dport

print 'hello'
sniff(filter='icmp', iface='ppp0', prn=icmp_callback)
```

it works flakily - why? `ping -c 2 8.8.8.8` doesn't trigger a .show

Comment: This works for me. Are you sure you get a response?

Comment: logging was suppressing it

Comment: grrr - the frigging thing stopped working - WTF!! http://storage8.static.itmages.com/i/16/0715/h_1468547235_2559921_f5eca5aac6.png

Comment: @Yoel could you take a look at the image

Comment: Perhaps you don't receive _ICMP_ responses? Try removing the filter and see what happens.